# Telegram bot: Multiple bots with different routes on same domain

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am using [Telegram Bot Php-Sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk). As the question is self explanatory, I am trying to run multiple bots on same domain but different routes. I have a live bot with webhook setup at mybot.domain.com/someroute and a staging bot at mybot2.domain.com/someroute. Both are at different servers. Today I created a new bot, created a new Controller and passed bot token inside this Controller's Constructor e.g.

```
class BotController extends Controller{
function __construct() {
   config(['telegram.bot_token'=>'my_bot_token');
}
}
```

I have a new webhook for this new bot as mybot2.domain.com/DifferentRoute. But since the time of deployment and webhook setup for this new bot, my all 3 bots are not responding. I am not getting any chat data on getWebhookUpdate function.
Need guidance Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query string to distinguish between bots.

For instance, bot A use `https://example.com/hook?bot=MyBot`, and you can identify them in code.